# JSch SFTP put to IBM z/OS fails :failed to write file; nested exception is 3: Permission denied

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, mainframe, zos

I am trying to put file via SFTP to mainframe using JSch.

Here is the code:

```
public void uploadFile(String contents) throws Exception {
    JSch.setLogger(new JSCHLogger());
    connectIfDisconected();
    LOGGER.info("Channel isConnected=: " + channel.isConnected());
    OutputStream os = channel.put("//!DTS4.UP.G5TB4.S60301");
    os.write(contents.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}

protected void connectIfDisconected() throws JSchException {
    if (!session.isConnected()) {
        LOGGER.info(LogEvent.create(".connectIfDisconected()", "Reconnecting session and channel..."));
        session.connect();
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.exit();
        }
        channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    } else if (!channel.isConnected()) {
        LOGGER.info(LogEvent.create(".connectIfDisconected()", "Reconnecting channel..."));
        channel.connect();
    }
}
```

Here is the session configuration:

```
session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
Properties config = getProperties(host, port);
session.setConfig(config);
...
...
protected Properties getProperties(String host, int port) throws JSchException {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", strictHostChecking ? "yes" : "no");
    config.put("kex", "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1");
    config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
    return config;
}
```

Session is connected fine!

While I'm trying to put file I'm getting the following exception on line

```
OutputStream os = channel.put(targetFile);
```

```
com.three60t.tex.app.exceptions.business.BusinessException: Error while delivering to Client communicator : Permission denied
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.utils.DefaultReporter.reportError(DefaultReporter.java:68)
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.transformationService.InternalTransformationService.reportError(InternalTransformationService.java:439)
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.transformationService.InternalTransformationService.deliver(InternalTransformationService.java:378)
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.transformationService.InternalTransformationService.doDeliver(InternalTransformationService.java:314)
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.transformationService.InternalTransformationService.transform(InternalTransformationService.java:305)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.three60t.tex.communication.message.handler.MessageDispatcher.dispatchToObject(MessageDispatcher.java:722)
        at com.three60t.tex.communication.message.handler.MessageDispatcher.doExecuteObject(MessageDispatcher.java:543)
        at com.three60t.tex.communication.message.handler.MessageDispatcher.access$200(MessageDispatcher.java:77)
        at com.three60t.tex.communication.message.handler.MessageDispatcher$1.run(MessageDispatcher.java:264)
        at com.three60t.tex.communication.message.handler.MessageDispatcher$3.run(MessageDispatcher.java:444)
        at com.three60t.concurrent.executor.v2.RunnableWithTimings.run(RunnableWithTimings.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 3: Permission denied
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:753)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:700)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:694)
        at com.three60t.integration.tradeimporters.sftp.DtccSftpClient.uploadFile(DtccSftpClient.java:34)
        at com.three60t.integration.tradeimporters.sftp.SFTPTransportDtcc.upload(SFTPTransportDtcc.java:41)
        at com.three60t.framework.communication.integration.SFTPTransport.upload(SFTPTransport.java:148)
        at com.three60t.integration.tradeimporters.sftp.SFTPTransportDtcc.upload(SFTPTransportDtcc.java:25)
        at com.three60t.integration.tradeimporters.sftp.SFTPTransportDtcc.deliver(SFTPTransportDtcc.java:55)
        at com.three60t.integration.posttrade.transformationService.InternalTransformationService.deliver(InternalTransformationService.java:362)
        ... 15 more
```

When I'm trying the same using terminal everything works fine!

```
sftp XXXX@fdmoverspse.dtcc.com
Connecting to fdmoverspse.dtcc.com...
XXXX@fdmoverspse.dtcc.com's password: 
sftp> put myfile.xml //!DTS4.UP.G5TB4.S60301
Uploading myfile.xml to //!DTS4.UP.G5TB4.S60301
myfile.xml       100% 7901     7.7KB/s   00:00   
sftp>
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "bug" in `ChannelSftp.glob_remote` that strips the second slash, if the path starts with two slashes.

Instead of this:

```
if(!pattern_has_wildcard){
  if(!dir.equals("/"))
    dir+="/";
  v.addElement(dir+Util.unquote(_pattern));
  return v;
}
```

The code should be like:

```
if(!pattern_has_wildcard){
  if(foo != 0)
    dir+="/";
  v.addElement(dir+Util.unquote(_pattern));
  return v;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Will try to report that bug!

Comment: looks like putting the file with 3 slashes might have worked ///!DTS4.UP.G5TB4.S60301

Answer (score 2):

I was able to put the file using [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj). There is a simple client that works for me:

```
public class DtccSftpSshjClient {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Log.getLogger(DtccSftpSshjClient.class);
private String hostname;
private String username;
private String password;

private SSHClient client;


public DtccSftpSshjClient(String hostname, String username, String password) throws IOException {
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(hostname);
    client.authPassword(username, password);
}

public void upload(String refId, String message, String dest) {
    try {
        LocalSourceFile messageFile = new InMemoryTradeFile(message, refId);
        SFTPClient sftp = client.newSFTPClient();
        sftp.put(messageFile, dest);
        sftp.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.toString());
    }

}

public void closeConnection() throws IOException {
    client.disconnect();
}

private class InMemoryTradeFile extends InMemorySourceFile {

    String message;
    String refId;

    public InMemoryTradeFile(String message, String refId) {
        this.message = message;
        this.refId = refId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return refId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLength() {
        return message.getBytes().length;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.